# Writing a query with more than 8000 keywords to retrieve the unique records that contains those keywords

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

I am totally new to both elasticsearch, and Linux. I started learning them because of a project 2 weeks ago. So, sorry if my question is too simple. 
It is been 2 weeks that I am trying to write a query that helps me to find out the number of unique records that are returned based on a list of keywords (8000 keywords) from a repository.Here is the code that I came up with:

```
 curl http://localhost:9200/INDEXED_REPOSITORY/_search?q="constant_score" : {"filter" : { "terms" : { "description" : ["heart", "cancer", and 7000 more keywords that I just pasted here]}}}}
```

But I get the following errors:

```
Couldn't resolve host 'constant_score'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host ':'
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 8

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host ':'
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 2

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'terms'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host ':'
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 2
```

I do not get what I am doing wrong. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: You might want to URL encode your query 'q', thats why you seeing errors such as "curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'terms'"

Comment: @printfmyname what do you mean by encoding q? Can you please direct me to some tutorials regarding this?

Comment: I think this answers your question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86729/any-way-to-encode-the-url-in-curl-command. Just make sure you have everything starting from 'q' to last '}' inside quotations. since you already used " double quotations, use single quotations ' to wrap your date

Answer (score 0):

I prefer passing the query using the -d option of curl instead of the query string.
This should work:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/INDEXED_REPOSITORY/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "description": [
            "heart",
            "cancer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```